# docker push not actually updating ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I am pushing a docker image to AWS ecr. The issue is the ECR image is not updating. This is all running in a gitlab pipeline by the way.

```
running:  docker run 00boilerplate/api-service /bin/bash -c "cat /root/base_service_container/api-nginx.conf"
here in eval command
command:  docker run 00boilerplate/api-service /bin/bash -c "cat /root/base_service_container/api-nginx.conf"
output:  server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    charset utf-8;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    sendfile on;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    keepalive_timeout  0;

    location /static {
        alias /root/base_service_container/api-service/static;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/api-uwsgi.sock;

        # The following was taken from:  http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT, DELETE';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
    }
}

running:  docker tag 00boilerplate/api-service 844373124958.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/00boilerplate/api-service:latest
here in eval command
command:  docker tag 00boilerplate/api-service 844373124958.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/00boilerplate/api-service:latest
output:  
_repository:  {u'repositoryArn': u'arn:aws:ecr:us-west-2:844373124958:repository/00boilerplate/api-service', u'repositoryName': u'00boilerplate/api-service', u'registryId': u'844373124958', u'createdAt': 1495615399.0, u'repositoryUri': u'844373124958.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/00boilerplate/api-service'}
running:  docker push 844373124958.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/00boilerplate/api-service:latest
here in eval command
command:  docker push 844373124958.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/00boilerplate/api-service:latest
output:  The push refers to a repository [844373124958.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/00boilerplate/api-service]
ce4ac46c05a6: Preparing [repeated several times]
db782c8e6f00: Waiting [repeated several times]
ce4ac46c05a6: Pushed [repeated several times]
latest: digest: sha256:[THE SHA CODE] size: [THE SHA SIZE]

Image 00boilerplate/api-service successfully pushed to 00boilerplate/api-service repository.
```

So, as you can see docker claims that it has pushed successfully. However when I pull and cat the api-nginx.conf, it is not the same as the one in the image that I pushed (namely the /static path is missing).

```
(venv)Govindas-MacBook-Pro:api-service govindadasu$ docker pull 844373124958.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/00boilerplate/api-service:latest
latest: Pulling from 00boilerplate/api-service
386a066cd84a: Pull complete [repeated several times]
Digest: sha256:ff6c1fe9316e7a412436209a49a4b2bdbba9c012cb803a3cb734ab54642b7c66
Status: Downloaded newer image for 844373124958.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/00boilerplate/api-service:latest
(venv)Govindas-MacBook-Pro:api-service govindadasu$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                                               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
844373124958.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/00boilerplate/api-service   latest              fd8ca67df522        2 months ago        1.26 GB
hello-world                                                              latest              48b5124b2768        4 months ago        1.84 kB
(venv)Govindas-MacBook-Pro:api-service govindadasu$ docker run -i -t fd8ca67df522 /bin/bash
root@927e1c04055e:~/base_service_container/api-service# ls
Dockerfile  api-uwsgi.ini  before_run.sh  boilerplate_draj  ci_tests.sh  manage.py  scripts
root@927e1c04055e:~/base_service_container/api-service# cat ../api-nginx.conf 
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    charset utf-8;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    sendfile on;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    keepalive_timeout  0;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/api-uwsgi.sock;

        # The following was taken from:  http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT, DELETE';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see when I pull the image on my local machine, the api-nginx.conf file is different from the one that was in the image that was tagged and pushed. What could be the cause of the ECR not actually updating? If you have tips on things I should be trying, please offer them in the comments.

Comment: can you try deleting local image and then pulling ECR image?

Comment: @SaadAbdullah I just did that now. No change.

Comment: now run docker images and update answer.

Comment: also, did you build the image again after making change to nginx file? If no, then you have to build image again and push that to ECR.

Comment: ya i did run the docker image after re-pulling (after deleting the image) ... the api-nginx.conf was not correct still

Comment: @SaadAbdullah regarding building the image, as you can see the image that was pushed did have "/static" part in it. it was build on the gitlab container before being run (in order to cat the api-nginx.conf)

Comment: any further suggestions?